# Getting "unknown parameter name" error with synchronized

Tags: scala

With Scala 2.13.x, I am getting `error: unknown parameter name` with `synchronized`:

```
object ExpTest extends App {
  class Recorder {
    private var result = Vector.empty[Int]

    def onCompleted(): Unit = {
      synchronized(result = result :+ 1)
    }

    def results: Vector[Int] = synchronized(result)
  }
}
```

Error:

```
ExpTest.scala:7: error: unknown parameter name: result
      synchronized(result = result :+ 1)
                          ^
1 error
```

But with Scala 2.12.x, I am not getting `error: unknown parameter name`.

Any reason?

Comment: Apparently the name of the argument changed, that is why. - The compile believes you are trying to pass the `result` parameter. Try with braces instead `synchronized { result = result :+ 1 }`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - Can you please ellaborate? Why this change is required in Scala 2.13.x.

Comment: See the updated comment. The compiler believes you are passing a parameter to the `synchronized` method.